# Laravel ajax request not working for a foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I have collected some data in my controller.Now In my view,I have showed them inside an unordered list (ul) as a link.

```
<ul>
    <li><a>....</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now When I am trying to fire an ajax request,only last data (i.e,Last link in listed items) is responding to the ajax request.The Ajax script is not inside the foreach loop.Do I have to place the ajax script inside the foreach loop.Then,for each data there will be a script.won't it create a problem?

```
<ul>
@foreach ($brands as $brand)
     <li class='n1'><a href="{{$brand->id}}"  id="{{$brand->brand}}">{{$brand->brand}}</a></li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

my ajax script:

```
<script>

$('#{{$brand->brand}}').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }
    });

   $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:'/userproduct',
      data: { value: $('#{{$brand->brand}}').attr('href')},
      success:function(data) {
          console.log(data);
      }        
  });
});
</script>
```

In My Controller

```
public function userproduct(Request $request){
   $value=$request->input('value');
   return Response::JSON($value);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, `{{$brand->brand}}` as "id" doesn't make sense. You can do it like, 

`id="product-{{$brand->brand}}"`

As you're just writing `$('#{{$brand->brand}}').on('click',function(e){});` this means that, you're registering only one node.

#### How to overcome this?

Apply a specific class for those links. register the click event with that class. Use, HTML5 data-* api to get the link and like so. That's it.

Answer (score 2):

At first, made the following changes in `a` elements for example:

```
<a class="brand" href="{{url('userproduct')}}" data-id="{{$brand->id}}">
    {{$brand->brand}}
</a>
```

Then use the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $('a.brand').on('click',function(e) {
        var el = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: el.attr('href'),
            data: { value: el.attr('data-id')},
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }        
        });

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

This should work but make sure that, you've also declared a route using `post` method for `userproduct`, for example:

```
Route::post('/userproduct', 'SomeController@handlerMethodName');
```

Check the browser console to find out error details if it doesn't work and try to solve the issues.The workflow is okay and should work if everything went well.

---

*Note: There are other ways to do it (using different code/approach) but this is a simplified code depending on your code given in the question. For example, I could have used the `ul` to register the event handler using event delegation but this'll work as well.*

Comment: Thanks.It's Working.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `id` of the last item in your ajax. That's why only last link in listed items is responding to the `ajax` request. Use class instead of `id` like this:

```
<li class='n1'><a class="myclass" href="{{$brand->id}}">{{$brand->brand}}</a></li>
```

JS:

```
<script>
$('.myclass').on('click', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $.ajax({

        method: "POST",
        url: '/userproduct',
        data: {
            value: $(this).attr('href')
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(1);

        }

    });
});

</script>
```

It should work.

Comment: Mahfuzur Rahman if I edit my code as you say.Then how can i get the selected value.It will take the last link's value.

Comment: Is your ajax ok ? If ok then write code in your controller. `echo` the value you get into the method from ajax. I think you are trying to get some data using the brand id. But you have not written any code to get the data.